# import Nuxt.js modules globally

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a small project using **Nuxt.js** and I would like to know if there is any way to import some of my **modules** globally like

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import toastr from 'toastr'
import Vue from 'vue'
```

Because each time I create a new **page**, I import the same **modules**. So I would like to know if there is any way to call this module in the **boot** for example.

Answer (score 0):

In `plugins` folder you could create a `jquery.js` file and then in the `nuxt.config.js` you could have it define it.

```
 plugins: [
    {
      src: '~/plugins/jquery.js',
      ssr: 
    }
  ]
```

Once you have defined it, you could use them in all your pages/components without invoking it repeatedly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i'm talking about modules that i have installed using npm

Comment: Yes even then, npm/yarn, any package can go in the plugins.

Comment: Please show examples of what your jquery.js file looks like and how you then globally use jquery in a component. I'm doing exactly the same, but with `csv-parse` and this answer tells me nothing about how to do this.